# Tips and help on doubts for our first FATE adventure

Tags: fate, fate-core, star-wars

We have just started a Star Wars adventure with FATE.
As with every game, we found the first actions that for which we don’t know the best rule to apply.

Can you help me?

1. The jedi want to move a dumpster close to a landspeeder with telekinesis.
   He wants to use a FP (FATE point) with his aspect "Jedi". **Can he spend FP for every jedi action, big or small, or the action should be relevant for a FP?**
2. Down the street a block away from the jedi, there are 3 troopers seeking for him.
   The jedi wants, as single action, perform an hyperjump an land between them and attack them with a single lightsaber attack.
   I make him jump toward them as first action, and attacks started on the next round. **Are there other ways? So, could he make all his declaration as one action? (jump + attack 3 troopers)**
3. The next round the jedi wants to attack all 3.
   I choose to make them defend with a collaborative action, so they dodge with Athletics +2. **Is this a valid choice?**
4. On the next action, the jedi tried to cut the 3 blasters with a lightsaber attack.
   Weapons have no armor no stress points. **How could I check for damage on blasters?**
5. As a fast alternative, I tell him that if he succeed in the attack, he can spend a FP for each blaster he wants to cut.
   **Is this a valid choice?**
6. During the conflict above, a 4th trooper was pulling a boy to a speeder. The smuggler PC (Deceive +4 and Mind Games stunt) want to make the trooper give him the boy. The pc went to the trooper and said "give me the boy, buddy, you are under jedi attack!".
   The boy is the reason they fought for.

   6A. My first choice was a single opposite check: Deceive vs Will.
   But, I tought deceive him to give the boy should be difficult.

   6B. My second choice was a single opposite check: Deceive vs Will +bonus.
   But, I was not sure how to assign an arbitrary bonus for this difficuly,
   and I didn't want a single round dialog for such important deceive.

   6C. My final choice was a mental conflict: Deceive vs Will, assigning stress and consequences. The smuggler rolled +3 and got the boy at the first round.
   Although, I'm not confident that the timing of a mental conflict and fisical conflict can match.

   **What could be a good rule?**
7. The smuggler has Deceive +4. Will is used in opposition to deceive, and the most part of opponents has low will.
   The PC can easily:

   - First round: create an advantage on the opponent, with deceive.
   - Second round: deceive. If he deceive with advantage and a spend a FP on the Advantage, he has a bonus of: Skill+Advange+FP = +4 +2 +2, so he start with a +8 bonus.

- It means that if he wants he can almost convince anyone of everything?
- Could he so easily convince the trooper to give him the boy?
- **Or am I wrong in something?**

8. The droid character is a KX-droid (from Rogue one). He wants to resist to blasters instead of dodge.
   With Extra points he choose Armor:2.
   He dodge with +0 and takes damage reduced by armor, but we do not like this.

- **Is correct a stunt: defend with armor (+2) instead of Athletics?**
- **Or, is correct a stunt: defend with body (body is +4) instead of Athletics?**
- **Is damage reduced by :2, even with one of this stunts above?**

9. The droid wanted to hit the speeder to damage it.
   Is it realistic that a +4 body droid could damage a speeder? Yes, but not so simple.
   As a rule, speeder has no hull and just 1-2 stress, so with a check: Body(4) vs hull(4) the droid could destroy a speeder in a couple of rounds with little effort; but this is not realistic.

   **How can I rule that?**

   - Should add an arbitrary hull value to the speeder?
   - Should I add a Good difficulty (+3) at the action?
10. Both the jedi and the droid wanted to sto the speeder turning it upside down: one with telekinesis, the other with body.
    As above, there is no ability of speeder for an opposited skill check.

    - I said that it is a superb (+5) action.
    - They tried one by one and they failed the +5 skill check.
    - If the tried combined, they could have started with a +4 +1 = +5 bonus.

    **Is this correct?**

***Finished!***
That's out 10 doubts list.
Please explain us some of them.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. People are expected to vote only yes or no that an answer is useful, and the original poster can award one "this answer worked for me" checkmark. We discourage asking about multiple separate topics in the same question, because what do you do about an answer that's good on one question but flat-out wrong about three others? You can collect this into 5 good questions - 1+2 are your Jedi, 3+4+5 are about area attacks, 6+7 are about your smuggler deceive, 8+9 are about the droid, and 10 is teamwork. Ask them all! It'll be fun!

Comment: ok, let's do it

Comment: Cool! If you need help breaking it up, feel free to ask in chat or in Meta, but it should be pretty straightforward. You can keep the introduction the same and just ask a different group of questions each time. I don't think they really need too much more editing than that.